# Оформление страницы успешной оплаты для Робокассы

Tags: php, робокасса

Согласно документации Робокасса страница оповещения клиента - оплата прошла успешно - реализована как банальное `echo "Операция прошла успешно"`

Естественно, показывать такое Покупателю  - белая страница без оформления и строчка текста наверху - как минимум неприлично. При оформлении ответа внутри шаблона сайта результат выглядит лучше, но все равно остаются два минуса:
1. В личном кабинете Робокассы логи проведенных оплат сохраняются со всем исходным кодом страницы, думаю, при больших количествах оплаченных заказов Робокасса начнет ругаться.
2. Покупатель после оплаты возвращается не на страницу, откуда он ушел, а на некую страницу успешного платежа, тоже не всегда логично.

**Вопрос** - какие есть рабочие решения возврата покупателя после удачной оплаты на ту же страницу, откуда был инициирован переход на страницу оплаты Робокассы?

Пока что использую переадресацию на главную страницу сайта, вот такой код внутри файла success.php `header("Location:/");`, некоторые покупатели жалуются, что успевают увидеть белую страницу с той самой строчкой и затем переход на главную, на мобильных гаджетах переход еще более заметен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вопрос - какие есть рабочие решения возврата покупателя после удачной
>   оплаты на ту же страницу, откуда был инициирован переход на страницу
>   оплаты Робокассы?

При нажатии кнопки "Оплатить через Robokassa" - ставите куку из JS (например `pay_source_page` ): на какой странице пользователь был, перед тем как оплатить, и только потом отправляете юзера на робокассу.

После оплаты он попадает на `success.php` - там вы должны сделать `header("Location:" . $_COOKIE['pay_source_page']);die();` , при чём перед этим не должно выводиться никакого контента - тогда пользователь увидит белую страницу разве что в IE6.

Comment: ок, еще вместо куки можно передавать пользовательскую переменную, она будет возвращаться в ответе, НО как теперь на этой странице, куда мы его возвратили, показать покупателю, что оплата удачна? Пробовал передавать через get - ерунда полная, некрасиво.

Comment: @Сергей В. передавайте все данные об оплате, которые вернула робокасса через сессию то есть перед `Location` что-то типа `$_SESSION['payData'] = ...`. А как показать - это уже вне рамок этого вопроса)